# Ratios as independent variables cause outlieres

Tags: regression, classification, data-transformation, outliers, ratio

If you include Ratios as Independent Variables in a regression or classification problem I often face many outliers. This is a big problem when the ratios can take on bounded values such as $\frac{equity}{total assets}$, but an even bigger one if the ratio can take on unbounded values such as $\frac{equity}{debt}$
I head that is a big problem in various disciplines like Management, Economics and Sociology.

How can I deal with this problem? Does this problem always arise or only in certain settings?

Comment: If the ratio is always positive, taking logarithms often helps.

Comment: it is common to add an 'insignificant' amount to the denominator. for a company insignificant debt might be ? $1000.

Comment: @NickCox I have started to transform the data by taking logarithms later I switched to inverse hyperbolic sine, but I am looking for alternatives to data transformation. Furthermore I would like to have a rule of thumb and a mathematical explanation when the problem arises.

Comment: You should show us more about your data. There is no precise prescription in abstraction any more than a doctor can diagnose "I don't feel well". For example, you don't even make precise if any values are $\le 0$.  If you are adverse to transformation asinh is often more drastic than logarithm (in situations where both are applicable).

Comment: When the proportion is bounded between zero and one you could try quasibinomial family, even if numerator and denominator is not integers.